# why python code gets hang while executing in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, freeze

I am trying to parse a text file and load it in a dataframe. I got help with parsing the text file from stack overflow but with some tweaking. I parsed the text file into DataFrame in such a way that one line is considered to be one row. But When I slice the line by number of characters in to separate columns, it hangs indefinitely. I have followed the same step for parsing the other files but did not face this issue.

Output after parsing the file:

```
                                                      data
0         VL0002511CA       000000000682414100000000000...
1         VL0002511ZZ       000000000682414100000000000...
2         VL0002512  PRE1985000000000682414100000000000...
3         VL0002521CA       000000001888990100000000000...
4         VL0002521ZZ       000000001888990100000000000...
5         VL0002522  PRE1985000000001888990100000000000...
6         VL0002531CA       000000001223831100000000000...
7         VL0002531ZZ       000000001223831100000000000...
8         VL0002532  PRE1985000000001223831100000000000...
9         VL0007871CA       000000001463787100000000000...
10        VL0007871ZZ       000000001463787100000000000...
11        VL0007872  PRE1985000000001463787100000000000...
```

The code that gets hanged is given below: (In the below code I am trying to slice the data dataframe and put them in different columns.)

```
df['COLA'] = df.data.str[0:3]
df['COLB'] = df.data.str[3:9]
df['COLC'] = df.data.str[9:10]
df['COLD'] = df.data.str[10:12]
df['COLE'] = df.data.str[12:15]
df['COLF'] = df.data.str[15:17]
df['COLG'] = df.data.str[17:19]
df['COLH'] = df.data.str[19:21]
df['COLI'] = df.data.str[21:23]
df['COLJ'] = df.data.str[23:38]
df['COLK'] = df.data.str[38:43]
df['COLL'] = df.data.str[43:51]
df['COLM'] = df.data.str[51:56]
df['COLN'] = df.data.str[56:57]
df['COLO'] = df.data.str[57:64]
df= df.drop('data', axis=1)
```

I am not sure of why is it hangs when executing. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: What is size of dataframe? What is error? Does it work, if try only 10 or 100 rows (`df = df.ix[:10]`)?

Comment: I am not getting any error on this but when executing the code it gets hanged sometime. Sometime the code executes with no more than a minute but someother time it just gets hanged indefinitely and I usually interrupt the kernal. By the way the size of the dataframe is 92820800.

Comment: It executes easily for 100 rows. I guess the problem is with the large dataframe. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is size of your `RAM`? Hmmm, string operations are very memory consumed.

Comment: it is 8 GB RAM. how can I clear the memory before reading the file into dataframe ?

Comment: Hmmm, df with 92M rows is huge. Does your input file have only two columns? After splitting do you need all cols - `ColA` to `ColO` ? What is next processing - save df to new file or some else? If there are not confidental data, you can share it and I try to help.